# Reduce skewness of normalized weights with outliers

Tags: outliers, normalization, weights

I have a vector of values and I want to extract their weights so that they sum up to 1.

I currently use this simple formula for normalization: $ w^i = \frac{ x^i }{ \sum {x} }$

The problem is that large values will get almost all of the distribution, and that's not what I want. I'd like to reduce the impact of the outliers (small and big) and the difference between weights.

How can I do that? What techniques can I use?

---

### Examples

```py
values = pd.Series([1, 30, 50, 200])
weights = values / values.sum()

weights
0    0.003559  # <-- This weight is too small!
1    0.106762
2    0.177936
3    0.711744  # <-- This weight is too big!
```

Comment: Can you say more about your actual data and goal to be achieved by 'normalizing'?

Comment: @BruceET Sure. Each value in the series represents an indicator for a different stock (financial data); for example, the inverse volatility (standard deviation) of that stock. The weights will be used for portfolio sizing. Supposing my portfolio contains 10 companies, the goal is to avoid having `99%` of the portfolio in one single stock and the remaining `1%` divided among all the others.

Comment: However, I'd be happy even with a broader answer for different situations.

Comment: **Finance isn't my area,** but there are many possibilities. Issue is relevance for your situation.// If you really believe one stock is extremely stable, and your goal is to get a stable portfolio, then maybe investing mainly in that one stock is best idea. But I guess you don't _totally_ trust the inverse volatility weights. You could inflate all volatilities by same const., then use reciprocals as weights. Example in R: `x1 = c(2,30,40,60,200); v1 = 1/x1;  v2 = v1+.03; x2 = 1/v2;  x2/sum(x2)` returns
 $(0.02, 0.18, 0.21, 0.25, 0.33).$ Inflating by .02 gives $(0.02, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4).$